# No me inserta el registro

Tags: sql

Al momento de insertar me sale que se agregó exitosamente pero al revisar la base de datos no muestra el registro insertado.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
Dim qryInsert As String = "INSERT INTO sadcc (cc_grupo_compras,cc_nombre_comprador,cc_correo,cc_unidad)" & _
                                                        " VALUES('" & TxtNoComp.Text & "','" & TxtNombre.Text & "','" & TxtCorreo.Text & "','" & DdlCentro.SelectedValue & "')"
```

Alguien sabe a qué se debe ese error?

Comment: El SQL se ve bien. El problema está en alguna otra parte del código.

Comment: Este código parece vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. ¿Estás poniendo direcamente el valor del campo en la consulta?

Comment: Aparte, mejorar la pregunta: añadir el código relevante y etiquetar mejor -este problema no tiene nada que ver con [tag:visual-studio], parece que es más un problema con vba/Visual Basic/.net (?) y SQL Server/MySQL/base de datos (?)